# SELECT statement doesnt work in PL/SQL block

Tags: sql, plsql

I'm newbie in PL/SQL and I'm stuck on this query! 
When I'm running this command,

```
SELECT COUNT(*),AVG(SI.TOTALCOST)
FROM S2.CAR C, S2.SERVINV SI 
WHERE C.SERIAL = SI.SERIAL 
AND MAKE = 'JAGUAR'
AND MODEL = 'PRO';
```

directly on SQLPlus prompt, it works perfactly fine and shows the output! 
 
 But when I run the same query as a part of PL/SQL block, this way

```
SELECT COUNT(*) INTO v_visits, AVG(SI.TOTALCOST) INTO v_avg 
FROM S2.CAR C, S2.SERVINV SI
WHERE C.SERIAL = SI.SERIAL
AND MAKE = '&p_make'
AND MODEL = '&p_model';
```

it doesn't work! It gives me this error,

```
SELECT COUNT(*) INTO v_visits, AVG(SI.TOTALCOST) INTO v_avg
                               *
ERROR at line 7:
ORA-06550: line 7, column 32:
PL/SQL: ORA-00934: group function is not allowed here
ORA-06550: line 7, column 1:
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
```

I don't understand what's the problem here!
I looked over the internet, but couldn't find anything helpful!
 
Any help is appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is only one `into` statement allowed.  List the variables there.  This version also uses the more modern join syntax (which you should learn):

```
SELECT COUNT(*), AVG(SI.TOTALCOST)
INTO v_visits, v_avg 
FROM S2.CAR C join
     S2.SERVINV SI
     on C.SERIAL = SI.SERIAL
where MAKE = '&p_make' AND MODEL = '&p_model';
```